# How to differentiate $E[u(X)]=\int_a^b u(X)f(x;\theta) dx$ with respect to $\theta$.

Tags: statistics, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to prove that

$$E[u(X)]=0 \implies E[X^ku(X)]=0$$

when $X \sim Exp[\frac{1}{\theta}]$.

So far what I know is that I am supposed to take the derivative with respect to $\theta$ and use induction from there.

However, I am having trouble with the inductive step where $k=1$.

Since I am not sure how to differentiate the expression

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} \int_0^{\infty} u(x)\theta e^{-\theta x}dx$$.

I want to say that this expression equals

$$\int_0^{\infty}u(x)e^{-\theta x}dx + \int_o^{\infty}-xu(x)\theta e^{-\theta x}dx$$

but I am not sure if I am right and even if I were I do not know how to proceed from here.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: You ate integrating with respect to $x$. Then, you can commute the integral sign and the derivative and differentiate the integral argument. Then you will get your result.

Comment: Are you saying that I can do $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\theta e^{-\theta x}$ inside the integral?

Comment: Yes, since the integral exists (a necessary assumption) one can move the differentation inside. @hyg17

Comment: @hyg17 Exactly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!